# Error on Call on state 4 Xamarin.android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, xamarin

I try to play music from a stream url, I have this code

```
class AudioImplementation : ISound
{
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public AudioImplementation() { }

public Context ApplicationContext { get; private set; }

public void Initializer()
{
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.SetAudioStreamType(Stream.Music);     
}

public void Play(string aux)
{
    if (mediaPlayer == null)
    {
        Initializer();
    }
    try
    {
        mediaPlayer.SetDataSource(aux);
        mediaPlayer.Prepare();
        mediaPlayer.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //unable to start playback log error
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to start playback: " + ex);
    }
  }
}
```

But I am getting an error start called in state 4, mPlayer error. Can someone please help me or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You could set an `IOnPreparedListener` for `MediaPlayer`, so that `start()` method is called after `MediaPlayer` is prepared. Code like this :

```
 mediaPlayer.SetDataSource(aux);
 mediaPlayer.Prepare();
 mediaPlayer.SetOnPreparedListener(new MyListener(this));

 class MyListener : Java.Lang.Object, MediaPlayer.IOnPreparedListener
 {
     private AudioImplementation audioImplementation;

     public MyListener(AudioImplementation audioImplementation)
     {
         this.audioImplementation = audioImplementation;
     }

     public void OnPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
     {
         audioImplementation.mediaPlayer.Start();
     }
 }
```